# Not able to Run powerSHell script using SysInternal

Tags: powershell, sysinternals

I need to remotely run powershell commands on multiple windows servers using SysInternal tools but I tried a lot but it seems not to work . Any help is highly appreciated .

Servers.csv (file content)

```
10.10.10.100
10.0.0.111
```

Code :

```
$List = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Users\javed\Desktop\New\servers.csv"

foreach ($entry in $List) {
if (test-Connection -Cn $($entry.Name) -quiet) {
    & C:\Users\javed\Downloads\PsTools\psexec.exe \\$($entry.Name) -u "$($entry.Name)\Admin" -p 'P@ssword' -accepteula  cmd /c " HostName >> C:\Users\javed\Desktop\New\Script.log"
} else {
    "$computer is not online" >> C:\Users\javed\Desktop\New\Script.log
}
}
```

Output :

```
PS C:\Users\javed> C:\Users\javed\Desktop\New\Change-NetworkRoute.ps1

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

psexec.exe : The handle is invalid.
At C:\Users\javed\Desktop\New\Change-NetworkRoute.ps1:26 char:9
+         & C:\Users\javed\Downloads\PsTools\psexec.exe \\$($entry.Name) -u "$( 
...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The handle is invalid.:String) [], Re 
   moteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Connecting to 10.10.10.100...Couldn't access 10.10.10.100:
Connecting to 10.10.10.100...

PS C:\Users\javed>
```

Comment: This looks like PSExec is failing. That being said, why not use Powershell remoting?

Comment: Does your csv have a heading named "name"?

Comment: I have a limitation due to server hardening , cannot use PowerShell remoting .

Comment: @Itchydon : Yes it does have it .

Comment: Try removing the space between the ampersand and the path to psexec

Comment: @Itchydon : I just tried with below command but it still gives the same invalid handle error           `&C:\Users\javed\Downloads\PsTools\psexec.exe \\$($entry.Name) -u "Administrator" -p 'P@ssword' -accepteula  cmd /c " HostName >> C:\Users\javed\Desktop\New\Script.log"`

Comment: I have just tested your code and it works for me!

Comment: @Itchydon  : Did u RUN it for a domain machine and with Local Administrator Account ?

Comment: Actually the only thing I changed was to use a domain account as I only have a domain controller to test against at the moment (no local account)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your command line isn't completely evaluated, note that PSExec shows `\\$($entry.Name)` in the error rather then the actual name.
The correct way to troubleshoot this is to put the first put the command is a variable, show the variable, and then execute it:

```
$CommandLine = "C:\Users\javed\Downloads\PsTools\psexec.exe \\$($entry.Name) -u ..."
Write-Host $CommandLine # Confirm that this is the command line you expect
if (test-Connection -Cn $($entry.Name) -quiet) {
    &$CommandLine
} else {
```

Anyhow, it is a bad idea to use an external command line as PSExec including credentials to achieve something like this. Instead, I would use WMI to retrieve the actual name of the servers. Something like this:

```
$SPAdmin = "$($entry.Name)\Admin"
$Password = "P@ssword" | convertto-securestring 
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $SPAdmin, $Password 
$Computer = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Computersystem -ComputerName $entry.Name -Credential $Credential
Write-Host $Computer.Name
```